# Is there a way to center the page title on Android when using Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently changed to Xamarin Forms and notice that the title isn't centered at the top of the page for Android devices.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Here's an example of what I mean with the title:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to implement ShellRenderer in this case as you have Xamarin.Forms Shell Project.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using Japanese.Droid.CustomRenderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Shell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
        }

        protected override IShellToolbarTracker CreateTrackerForToolbar(Toolbar toolbar)
        {
            return new MyShellToolbarTracker(this, toolbar, ((IShellContext)this).CurrentDrawerLayout);
        }
    }

    public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override void SetAppearance(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);
            //Change the following code to change the icon of the Header back button.

            toolbar?.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.back);
        }
    }

    public class MyShellToolbarTracker : ShellToolbarTracker
    {
        public MyShellToolbarTracker(IShellContext shellContext, Toolbar toolbar, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) : base(shellContext, toolbar, drawerLayout)
        {
        }

        protected override void UpdateTitleView(Context context, Toolbar toolbar, View titleView)
        {
            base.UpdateTitleView(context, toolbar, titleView);
            for (int index = 0; index < toolbar.ChildCount; index++)
            {
                if (toolbar.GetChildAt(index) is TextView)
                {
                    var title = toolbar.GetChildAt(index) as TextView;
                    //Change the following code to change the font size of the Header title.
                    title.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, 20);
                    toolbar.SetTitleMargin(MainActivity.displayMetrics.WidthPixels / 4 - Convert.ToInt32(title.TextSize) - title.Text.Length / 2, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for MainActivity.cs

```cs
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetRealMetrics(displayMetrics);

        LoadApplication(new App());

        if (Window != null) Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        if (isPhone(this)) RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `TitleView`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
             x:Class="TitleViewSample.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="Hello World" HorizontalTextAlignement="Center"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>    
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view

Comment: Yes, in the same way using Shell you have `Shell.TitleView` as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar)

Comment: Interestingly, mine isn't in the center. Seems the back button is throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

As the title textview having wrapped width within toolbar not updating alignment on TextAlignment with center, you can update the layout params of the toolbar to matchparent and textview gravity as follows.

If the hamburger image added with custom image then need check that resoulution if that is too big just reduce it lower one

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MyRenderer))]//MainPage - navigation page
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class MyRenderer: MasterDetailPageRenderer
    { 
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
             base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);  
            for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
            {

                var title = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as TextView;
                if (title != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title.Text))
                {
                    title.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
                    title.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
                    var layoutParams = (AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar.LayoutParams)title.LayoutParameters;
                    layoutParams.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
                    toolbar.RequestLayout(); 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```